# Apache 2 on Solaris 10 image for Virtual Box compliation flags detection

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris

"The version of Apache 2.0 that ships with some operating systems, including some versions of Solaris and Linux, is compiled with the following flags:  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 "

How can i detect this ? Is there a way to query Solaris that installed apache is compiled in that way or not ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: I have istalled weblogic ,created a cluster and weblogic provides a plugin for apache in order to have some kind of software loadbalancer...there are tow versions of plugins for largefile support and normal...in the docs they specify to use one of them according to your needs ,system...

Comment: now i tried both and the plugin for that supports large file works only but that was trial and error like not a way of detecting how it was compiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running apache with the `-V` option which will print the build options this may contain what you want e.g. on an old Solaris 10 vm I have to hand it would be

```
/usr/apache2/bin/httpd -V
```

Comment: response is http://pastebin.com/zhJJqRRu : no sign of large file support ..but if tha mod_weblogic.so works i used that one.However I hate  "belive and do not research" thing..:)

Comment: as info this is how i star apache : svcadm -v enable /network/http:apache2
and thios is how i stop: svcadm disable /network/http:apache2
is there any better way ? cheers.